# Having Trouble Cube Root Long Division method: for 810

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

Division method for Cube Roots. Having trouble grasping why i get 9.328 instead of 9.321 like the calculator says. I fear there's some missing step in my algorithm, because every time i check the math, i keep getting 
2,086,016,000 (about 2 billion) divided by 260,587,200 (about 260 million) and while that borders 7 and 8, i don't see how it comes close to being 1 or 2.

when i multiply 300 x 932 x 932 x 8 i get 2,084,697,600 which fits nicely, even counting the spare change from the remaining two parts of the process.

Which means my process is wrong or ive got a persistent blind spot in my math.

[image]

ive highlighted in red where my numbers don't match a calculator. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work out the remainder from the second digit you have one factor of 3  (that digit) too few in the second and third subtrahends.  You should render

$81000-(300×9×9×3)-(30×9×3×3)-(3×3×3)=81000-72900-2430-27=5643$

and similarly in the following steps.

As a check, verify that $810000-5643=93^3$.

Comment: wait, so for the second and third, is the pattern
300x93x93x[3]x2...30x93x[3]x2...[3]x2x2, then
300x932x932x[3]x1...30x932x[3]x1...[3]x2x1, or does the pattern mutate more?

Comment: The factor you are missing in the second and third subtrahends is not always 3, it is the digit you added in that step.  Above it was 3, then it was 2, then it would be 8 but with the correct rendering the fourth digit drops to 1.  The second subtrahend is to be 30 × previous digits × new digit × new digit, the third is the cube of the new digit.

Comment: And note my checking procedure.  The radicand including attached zeroes, minus the remainder, is always the cube of the number formed by the generated digits.

Comment: so fixing my pattern, i need 6 instances of the digit rather than four? so in your 810000 example, there are six instances of 3, then for 5643000 there should be six instances of 2, then for whatever that results in, there should finally be six instances of x1, if i am understanding this pattern correctly?

Comment: That will work.